# Concatenate string values in array in a single field in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose that I have a series of documents with the following format:

```
{
    "_id": "3_0",
    "values": ["1", "2"]
}
```

and I would like to obtain a projection of the array's values concatenated in a single field:

```
{
    "_id": "3_0",
    "values": "1_2"
}
```

Is this possible? I have tried `$concat` but I guess I can't use `$values` as the array for `$concat`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Modern MongoDB releases you can. You still cannot "directly" apply an array to `$concat`, however you can use [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to work with the array elements and produce this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "values": { 
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$values",
        "initialValue": "",
        "in": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": [ { "$indexOfArray": [ "$values", "$$this" ] }, 0 ] },
            "then": { "$concat": [ "$$value", "$$this" ] },
            "else": { "$concat": [ "$$value", "_", "$$this" ] }
          }    
        }
      }        
    }
  }}
])
```

Combining of course with [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) in order to **not** "concatenate" with the `"_"` underscore when it is the "first" index of the array.

Also my additional "wish" has been answered with `$sum`:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "total": { "$sum": "$items.value" }
  }}
])
```

---

This kind of gets raised a bit in general with aggregation operators that take an array of items. The distinction here is that it means an "array" of "aguments" provided in the coded representation a opposed to an "array element" present in the current document.

The only way you can really do the kind of concatenation of items within an array present in the document is to do some kind of JavaScript option, as with this example in [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/):

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit( this._id, { "values": this.values.join("_") } );
    },
    function() {},
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Of course if you are not actually aggregating anything, then possibly the best approach is to simply do that "join" operation within your client code in post processing your query results. But if it needs to be used in some purpose across documents then mapReduce is going to be the only place you can use it.

---

I could add that "for example" I would love for something like this to work:

```js
{
    "items": [
        { "product": "A", "value": 1 },
        { "product": "B", "value": 2 },
        { "product": "C", "value": 3 }
    ]
}
```

And in aggregate:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "total": { "$add": [
            { "$map": {
                "input": "$items",
                "as": "i",
                "in": "$$i.value"
            }}
        ]}
    }}
])
```

But it does not work that way because [**`$add`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) expects arguments as opposed to an array from the document. Sigh! :(. Part of the "by design" reasoning for this could be argued that "just because" it is an array or "list" of singular values being passed in from the result of the transformation it is not "guaranteed" that those are actually "valid" singular numeric type values that the operator expects. At least not at the current implemented methods of "type checking".

That means for now we still have to do this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
   { "$unwind": "$items" },
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
        "total": { "$sum": "$items.value" }
   }}
])
```

And also sadly there would be no way to apply such a grouping operator to concatenate strings either.

So you can hope for some sort of change on this, or hope for some change that allows an externally scoped variable to be altered within the scope of a [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operation in some way. Better yet a new `$join` operation would be welcome as well. But these do not exist as of writing, and probably will not for some time to come.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the examples. Like I was thinking there isn't an easy solution to the problem... I guess I will end up doind another mapReduce but I was trying to avoid it because I already do a previous mapReduce to produce that data.
Do you know if there is some way of chaining mapReduce operation in nodeJS with the MongoDB driver?

Comment: @Eylen Not really, and meaning without outputting to a collection and running it all again. It's just not possible otherwise. But perhaps if you consider what you are doing in your initial mapReduce operation then a subsequent step may not be necessary. Of course there is always the "finalize" method. Which would seem like the logical conclusion unless you need further "grouping" once concatenated.

Comment: Yes, I need to do another grouping totally different to the first one. I will give it another thought to see if I can take any other approach.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) operator together with the [substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        values: {
            $reduce: {
              input: '$values',
              initialValue: '',
              in: {
                $concat: ['$$value', '_', '$$this']
              }
            }
        }   
    }       
},
{
    $project: {
        values: { $substr: ['$values', 1 , -1]}
    }       
}])
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting in `Mongo 4.4`, the [`$function`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/function/index.html) aggregation operator allows applying a custom javascript function to implement behaviour not supported by the MongoDB Query Language.

For instance, in order to concatenate an array of strings:

```
// { "_id" : "3_0", "values" : [ "1", "2" ] }
db.collection.aggregate(
  { $set:
    { "values":
      { $function: {
          body: function(values) { return values.join('_'); },
          args: ["$values"],
          lang: "js"
      }}
    }
  }
)
// { "_id" : "3_0", "values" : "1_2" }
```

`$function` takes 3 parameters:

- `body`, which is the function to apply, whose parameter is the array to join.
- `args`, which contains the fields from the record that the `body` function takes as parameter. In our case `"$values"`.
- `lang`, which is the language in which the `body` function is written. Only `js` is currently available.