# How do get the last substring using the MongoDB aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have these documents

```js
> db.coll.find().toArray()
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a36c3e218948d0722457078"),
        "locality" : "Nasimi, Baku, Azerbaijan"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a36c3e218948d0722457079"),
        "locality" : "Garland, TX, USA"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a36c3e218948d072245707a"),
        "locality" : "Halytskyi District, Lviv, Lviv Oblast, Ukraine"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a36c3e218948d072245707b"),
        "locality" : "Tozeur, Tunisia"
    }
]
```

I would like to get only the country, i.e. whatever is after the last comma (`', '`).

e.g.

```
[
    "Azerbaijan",
    "USA",
    "Ukraine",
    "Tunisia"
]
```

I've managed to get the index of the first comma and what is after that but I can't figure out how to to get the last one.

```js
db.coll
  .aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
        lastIndexOf: { $indexOfBytes: [ '$locality', ', ' ] },
        locality: '$locality',
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        lastIndexOfPlusTwo: { $add: [ '$lastIndexOf', 2 ] },
        locality: '$locality',
      }
    },
    {
      $project: { country: { $substr: [ '$locality', '$lastIndexOfPlusTwo', -1 ] } }
    }
  ]).pretty()

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a36c3e218948d0722457078"),
    "country" : "Baku, Azerbaijan"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a36c3e218948d0722457079"),
    "country" : "TX, USA"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a36c3e218948d072245707a"),
    "country" : "Lviv, Lviv Oblast, Ukraine"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a36c3e218948d072245707b"),
    "country" : "Tunisia"
}
```

This works but it loads all the results in memory in the JavaScript Mongo Shell but would be ideal if it can be done with a single MongoDB aggregation command.

```js
var res2 = db.coll.aggregate();

res2 = res2.toArray().map(function(doc) {
  var lastIndex = doc.locality.lastIndexOf(',');
  return doc.locality.slice(lastIndex + 2);
});

[ "Azerbaijan", "USA", "Ukraine", "Tunisia" ]
```

Maybe with [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/), [$split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query.

`{"$arrayElemAt":["$$locality",-1]}` to access the last element from the array.

```
db.coll.aggregate([{"$project":{
  "_id":0,
  "last":{
    "$let":{
      "vars":{"locality":{"$split":["$locality",","]}},
      "in":{"$arrayElemAt":["$$locality",-1]}
    }
  }
}}])
```

Comment: that was it! I tried for hours but I knew there are people smarter than me online. thanks ☺️

Comment: @user2683814 Is it possible to use `$trim` with `$arrayElemAt`? I am trying to             `model:{
              $let:{
                vars: {
                    modelsubstr: { $split:["$_id.model","("] },
                },
                in: { $trim: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$modelsubstr", 0] } }
              }
            }`but does not work. I get `$trim found an unknown argument: $arrayElemAt`

Comment: @user1665355 You have an error in your syntax. It would have to be sth like `{$trim: {input: {$arrayElemAt: ...}}}`. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trim/
However, `$trim` only accepts strings as `input`-argument, not arrays, so you would have to rejoin your array after the split into a string before passing it to `$trim`. A hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882552/concatenate-string-values-in-array-in-a-single-field-in-mongodb