# How to define Projection in PDI for mongodb input step

Tags: mongodb, pdi

Following is the structure of the document i have in a collection in MongoDB

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f48e358d43721376c397f53"
    },
    "heading": "this is heading",
    "tags": ["tag1","tag2","tag3"],
    "categories": ["projA", "projectA2"],
    "content": ["This", "is", "the", "content", "of", "the", "document"],
    "timestamp": 1598612312.506219,
    "lang": "en"
}
```

I only want to select **ID** and **heading** fields (like writing query "select id, heading from collection"). the projection entries are not working, I have tried a few different approaches after searching the internet. Filtering, sorting, grouping is working but projection is not.
How do i define projection in Mongodb input step in PDI to select certain fields from a collection I have tried specifying projection in query and [field expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI3ZA.png) but it is not working.

Also i am having trouble [concatenating string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64764408/select-mongodb-aray-element-in-a-single-field-in-pentaho-pdi) in the same step. so i would appreciate if someone can help me with that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem in this step by specifying projection like this

```
[{$project: {heading: 1}}]
```

[image]